# 15 people, 5 groups of 3, over 7 months

Tags: combinatorics

I have a list of $15$ people and I need to put them into 5 unique groups of $3$. They're going to meet once a month over the next $7$ months. I want everyone to be in different groups every month.

Rules:

1. {1,2,3} is the same as {3,2,1}
2. By unique I mean that no two members appear in the same group twice.

Is it possible to have unique groups for $7$ months?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. What prevents you from dividing them into $5$ groups? What's not unique about a group? What's the issue with the months? Are they meeting once a month, and each time you want different groups to meet each other? What's the story with the meetings? Who's meeting who - two groups meet each other, or do the people on the same group meet each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Kirkman's schoolgirl problem, and it has a solution which you can find here.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Make 5 groups of 3 for the first month. Then rotate just the last member from each group into the previous group. That gives different groups for 5 months.

Then rotate the first member from each group once, and rotate the last members again. This gives 10 months.

**Here is what I mean:**

012 345 678 9ab cde

015 348 67b 9ae cd2

018 34b 67e 9a2 cd5

01b 34e 672 9a5 cd8

01e 342 675 9a8 cdb

**next groups:**

312 645 978 cab 0de

315 648 97b cae 0d2

318 64b 97e ca2 0d5

31b 64e 972 ca5 0d8

31e 642 975 ca8 0db

Comment: depending on the problem statement, either they may allow or disallow having two people appear in the same group of three more than once.  Potentially 312 is not different enough from 315.

Comment: It is true that I chose what seemed to be the most obvious meaning of an ambiguous question. I interpreted "group" as "set", and in my answer all the sets of 3 are different.